# Php + mysqli + не стандартный порт

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

centos
пробросил порт БД с удалённого сервера на этот сервер
теперь пытаюсь к нему подключиться из PHP скрипта и не могу
скрипт постоянно цепляет меня к локальной БД на 3306 порту, а новая БД проброшена на 3307 порту.
полный ппц в том что какой бы я порт не указывал в PHP скрипте, он рапортует что исправно коннектится к нему, но на самом деле он заходит всё в тот же 3306 порт

проверял "telnet localhost 3307", всё работает, БД видна, но PHP почемуто упирается

чтото вроде такого накидал

```
function connect()
{
    /* Подключение к серверу MySQL */
    ini_set("mysqli.default_port", 3307);
    echo ini_get("mysqli.default_port") . "<br>";

    $this->link = new mysqli($this->server, $this->login, $this->pass, $this->db);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Подключение к серверу MySQL невозможно. Код ошибки: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit;
    } else {
        $this->link->set_charset("utf8");
        printf("Успех!");
    }
}
```

почему не в new mysqli() порт указываю? это из-за того что указывал, но PHP его ингнорировал, искал так сказать альтернативные пути

Comment: > почему не в new mysqli() порт
> указываю? это из-за того что указывал,
> но PHP его ингнорировал, искал так
> сказать альтернативные пути

Честное слово, впервые слышу. Можно об этом поподробней или линк на мануал?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$this->server` у вас localhost ?

надо 127.0.0.1 иначе он через unix socket будет подключаться.

Comment: спасибо за совет  
помогло!  
  
я в/etc/my.cfg комментировал сокет, но не помогало, поэтому этот вариант в расчет взят был на половину

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->link = new mysqli($this->server, $this->login, $this->pass, $this->db, 3307);
```

не?

Comment: я же написал  
> "почему не в new mysqli() порт указываю?...  "

так что не работает, пробовал, на win работает(любые варианты), на linux никакие варианты не работают, всегда ломится на 3306