# Не учитывается параметр --port терминале mysql

Tags: mysql, ssh-tunnel

Добрый день.

Пол дня не могу понять в чем проблема. У меня на сервере (CentOS6) установлен mysql-server. И на другом сере стоит все то же.

Поднят SSH-туннель на удаленный сервер, который на порт 3307 "прикручивает" удаленный mysql.

Запускаю`terminal localhost 3306` - выдает приглашение (там кракозябры, но подключение есть). Запускаю терминал на порт 3307 без туннеля - выдет ошибку, с туннелем - такую же кракозябру. Предполагаю - туннель работает корректно.

Ни из perl, ни из консольного приложения mysql не удается подключиться к удаленному серверу.

из консоли `mysql --host=localhost --port=3307 --user=dbuser --password=dbpassword dbname` - возврашает ошибку

```
RROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

На локальном сервере нет такого mysql-пользователя

Выполняю `mysql --host=localhost --port=3307` - подключается, но к локальному серверу (там другие базы)

Выполняю `mysql --host=localhost --port=33071` - подключается, но к локальному серверу (там другие базы)

Аналогичный эффект на удаленном сервере. Полное игнорирование параметра --port.

И из Perl - тот же эффект (собственно надо именно там работать).

Может кто сталкивался с подобной ситуацией?

Comment: А напишите как порт пробросили? Не могло получиться так, что вы с 3306 на 3307 пробросили? Так кстати часто делают, чтобы не экранировать локальный порт.

Comment: Только что нашел решение... Всю голову вчера взорва и ночью уснуть не мог... надо localhost заменить 127.0.0.1 http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/232121/php-mysqli-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82

Comment: Надо localhost заменить 127.0.0.1 См. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/232121/php-mysqli-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82

Answer (score 1):

Есть два способа соединения с MySQL-сервером: через сокет и через сеть. Когда в качестве хоста вы пишите localhost - соединение по умолчанию идет через сокет, когда пишите IP-адрес - через сеть. Поэтому в случае localhost директива `port` игнорируется - для соединения через сокет сетевой порт не нужен.

Помимо явного указания IP-адреса 127.0.0.1 вместо localhost, существует еще одно решение - перенаправить все соединения через сеть. Для этого в конфигурационном файле my.cnf следует обнаружить и удалить все директивы `socket` и перезагрузить сервер. При этом следует убедиться, что сервер привязан к текущему IP-адресу

```
[mysqld]
...
bind-address                   = 0.0.0.0
```